# Why don't "monkey" and "donkey" rhyme?

Tags: etymology, pronunciation-vs-spelling, rhymes

How come the words monkey /ˈmʌŋki/ and donkey /ˈdɒŋki, ˈdɔŋki/ don't rhyme? What is their derivation? Or perhaps they do rhyme, depending on where one is from.

Comment: They seem to rhyme for me. At least the second syllable does, which is all that normally counts.

Comment: No idea why this question got downvoted. But thanks to mack's superb answer, this question will get a lot of views.

Comment: @curiousdannii: by the usual definition of rhyme, words have to have the same vowel in a *stressed* syllable (and then be identical from that point till the end of the word). The second syllables of "donkey" and "monkey" are unstressed.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I suspect the question was downvoted because the downvote tooltip mentions lack of research as a reason for downvoting.

Comment: @sumelic That's not a definition I've heard before, but okay.

Comment: @curiousdannii: it's mentioned in Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhyme#English

Comment: @AndrewLeach compared to the 80% of questions being posted, it's a gem. Anyway, how would you find the answer as to "why" the two words don't rhyme? Is that a general knowledge question, would you find the answer looking up the definitions in an online dictionary?

Comment: @Mari I'm not sure what kind of answer this question could have other than that they have different sounds.

Comment: @curiousdannii yes, but the point is the two words are practically spelt the same way, and yes, I know spelling doesn't reflect how words are pronounced. But see John Mack's answer, an explanation for the apparent discrepancy. Did you *know* about the etymology of *donkey*, this is not general knowledge, this is a perfect question for linguists and etymologists, *thumps fist on table*!

Comment: @curiousdannii okay, I'll bite: that's the *only* definition of perfect rhyming in *every* language I am remotely familiar with. What is yours, pray tell?

Comment: @Mari Well there are at least 12 monophthongs in English and only five vowel letters, so it's perfectly ordinary for one letter to have two sounds. Asking about the etymology would be an interesting question, but this doesn't strictly ask that, it just asks why they don't rhyme, and the answer is that they have different sounds.

Comment: @Reg I guess from looking at that Wikipedia page the definition of rhyme I learnt growing up is the "syllabic" definition, not the "perfect" definition. Despite the name, I don't see how any definition is objectively better than another. But note the question doesn't specifically ask about perfect rhymes, so any of the others should be fair game.

Comment: @curiousdannii *What is their derivation?* asks the OP

Comment: @Mari okay. But that's not the main question

Comment: @curiousdanni  Acknowledging the very enlightening discussion on rhyme carried through this series of comments, I have to turn back to the Oxford Dictionary's observation in respect to 'donkey' that 'the original pronunciation apparently rimed with monkey ...'   The question of how exactly the spelling (as I believe), and the pronunciation (as the OED claims) morphed from 'dun' to 'don' over time was not addressed by my answer, but I have nowhere as much expertise in that particular area as some of the authors of the previous comments, including yourself and Mari-Lou.

Comment: The OED's assertion that donkey and monkey 'rimed' in times past appears to be based on the following verse by John Wolcot (1738-1819) in his poem (under the pseudonym Peter Pindar) 'Rowland for an Oliver':  

_Who never dipp'd her muzzle in the Spring.
Thou think'st thyself on Pegasus so steady;  
But, Peter, thou art mounted on a Neddy:  
Or in the London phrase, thou Devonshire monkey,  
Thy Pegasus is nothing but a Donkey._    
Of course the rhyme may have been 'forced' rather than natural, but I simply quote the OED source in order to throw light on the OED's assertion.

Comment: Because English has a way of making a monkey out of you when you try to infer some "pattern".

Comment: I grew up in Northern New Jersey and "monkey" and "donkey" were exact rhymes there..

Comment: As has been pointed out before many times, no one should expect English spelling to indicate pronunciation, so the fact that two words are spelled alike says nothing about whether they rhyme. If you start with the idea that they **should** rhyme, you're not going to be satisfied.

Answer (score 13):

The Oxford English Dictionary has this to say about *donkey*:

> A recent word, apparently of dialect or slang origin.  As the original
>   pronunciation apparently rimed with monkey (whence the spelling),
>   suggestions have been made that the word is a derivative of dun adj.
>   (cf. dunnock hedge-sparrow), or more probably, a familiar form of
>   Duncan (cf. the other colloquial appellations, Dicky, Neddy).

I'm inclined to accept *dun* as the source.  Again the OED on *dun*:

> Of a dull or dingy brown colour... like the hair of an ass...

The OED quotes sources for *dun*, such as:

> 1562 J. heywoord Proverbs and Epigrams (1867) 139 The dun Asse hath
>   trode on both thy feete.

But *dun* was also what the OED calls a quasi-proper name for any horse and quotes Chaucer:

> c.1386 Manciple's Prologue 5 Ther gan our hoost for to Iape and
>   pleye, And seyde, sires, what Dun is in the Myre.

Turning to the OED on the word *monkey*:

> Of uncertain origin.  .. it is not unlikely that the proper name may
>   represent an otherwise unrecorded Middle Low German (1100-1600AD)
>   moneke, Middle Dutch (1150-1500AD) monekijn, a collquial word for
>   monkey and that this may have been brought to England by show-men from
>   the continent. The MLG and MDu word would appear to be a diminutive of
>   (with suffix -ke, -kijn (see -kin)) some form of the Roman word
>   which appears as early modern French monne (16-17th century), Italian
>   monna (earlier mona)...

The OED doesn't speculate where the Roman/Italian word came from, but it has carried down into modern Spanish where the word for monkey is *mono*.  The word *man* according to the OED includes old forms such as *mon* and *monne*.  Whether the author of this entry didn't want to buy into Darwinian debate, or there's a good philological reason to discount any link between the words *man* and *monkey* I'll leave to the experts.

The suffix *-kin*, which appears to be the origin for *-key* in both *monkey* and *donkey* simply signifies kin, as in relation, or a group having common attributes.  Hence (I'd suggest) donkey is kin to *dun* (horse), and monkey is kin to that class of animals (apes and perhaps man) formerly described as *mone*, *monne* and *mona*.

But yes, returning to the observation from the head of my comments here, the OED holds that donkey used to be pronounced 'done-key' rhyming with monkey as we currently say it.  This assertion is based on the following verse by John Wolcot (1738-1819) in his 1790 poem (under the pseudonym Peter Pindar) 'Rowland for an Oliver':

> Who never dipp'd her muzzle in the Spring.
>   Thou think'st thyself on Pegasus so steady;
>   But, Peter, thou art mounted on a Neddy:
>   Or in the London phrase, thou Devonshire monkey,
>   Thy Pegasus is nothing but a Donkey.

Of course the rhyme may have been 'forced' rather than natural, but I simply quote the OED source in order to throw light on the OED's assertion.

As for the OED's speculation that the word *donkey* might have come from *Duncan*, a possible familiar name for an ass (but no references cited), it is interesting to speculate that the word could have actually moved in the other direction, that is to say *Duncan* being derived from *dun-kin*.

Comment: As a side note, Shakespeare used "dun" in sonnet 130 to mean brown like a horse.

Comment: The OED is less coy about associating manikin or mannequin (a model of a man or woman used for art or display, and sometimes referring to a dwarf or contemptuously of a person) with the Dutch (manneken) meaning 'man' with the suffix '-kin' (the suffix suggestive of a diminutive but associated type).  Note the similarity to the Middle Dutch 'monekijn' quoted in the OED entry for monkey.

Comment: The origin of "Duncan" is, I think, settled. Yes, it is related to the color "dun", but not to diminutive "kin".

Answer (score -1):

I pronounce donkey as dohn-ki, and monkey as muhn-ki, which don’t rhyme. I have never heard them be pronounced another way, but it seems like other people pronounce them in a way that is different from mine, so depending on how you say them they could rhyme. If you wanted to use them for lyrics in a song then you might be able to make them rhyme by pronouncing them differently, and I’m sure you would be understood. I used Oxford Languages for the derivation of donkey, which says, “late 18th century (originally pronounced to rhyme with monkey): perhaps from dun, or from the given name Duncan” so I think you would be understood if you pronounce it in a way that rhymes with monkey. Maybe I am in the minority of people who pronounce them differently.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Community-bot doesn't really help here. A link to your supporting evidence would definitely be good; but the main issue is that the answer doesn't answer the question of ***why*** they are pronounced differently.